# Writing the following curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, phonegap-build

How would I write the following Curl in PHP?

I need to automate this process in php.

```
$ curl -F file=@/Users/alunny/index.html -u andrew.lunny@nitobi.com -F 'data={"title":"API V1 App","package":"com.alunny.apiv1","version":"0.1.0","create_method":"file"}' https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps
```

Here is the link to the Phonegap Build API.

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/developer_api_write.md.html#_post_https_build_phonegap_com_api_v1_apps

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have tried so far...

```
<?php

$url = 'https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps';
$file = 'mobilecontainer.zip';

$fields = array(
    'title' => 'Test App',
    'create_method' => 'file',
    'private' => 'false'
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, 'true');

$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use CURL options improperly.

1. `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` option disables support for the `@` prefix for
   uploading files in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` which is exactly what you
   need to use.
2. `CURLOPT_POST` option expects a boolean value (`true` or `false`),
   although `count($fields)` in your case will be evaluated to `true`
   anyway.
3. `-F` option in the source curl command forces `Content-Type` value
   to `multipart/form-data`. This mean that in PHP you have to pass
   data to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` as array. This array should contain two
   elements: `'data'` - json-encoded data, and `'file'` - link to file
   to upload.

So the code should look like this:

```
$url = 'https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/apps';
$data = array(
    'title' => 'Test App',
    'package' => 'com.alunny.apiv1',
    'create_method' => 'file',
    'version' => '0.1.0',
);
$post = array(
    'data' => json_encode($data),
    'file' => '@mobilecontainer.zip',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: thank you, how would you add a username and if it asks you for a password, how would you fill it in with curl?

Comment: In the source curl command server authentication is used by `-u` option. In PHP its counterpart is `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option. It expects a string in the `[username]:[password]` format.