# cURL file download works on PHP 5.3 not on 5.5

Tags: php, apache, curl, download, php-5.5

I have two servers running similar web apps in different software versions.

Both servers are running CentOS 6.5

One has Apache 2.2 php 5.3

And the other one is running Apache 2.4 php 5.5

One of the key functions of this app is periodically download a CSV file from a remote URL

This is done using cURL and the following code:

```
$filename = 'export.csv';
$url = 'http://www.someaddress.com/export/' . $filename;
$curl = curl_init();
$fd = fopen(DIR_FS_ADMIN . 'temp/' . $filename , "w");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fd);
curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

As you can see a very simple bit of code that works great in PHP 5.3

This are the results of curl_getinfo()

```
[content_type] => text/csv
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 209
[request_size] => 95
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 1.98925
[namelookup_time] => 0.816404
[connect_time] => 0.817009
[pretransfer_time] => 0.831392
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 13564110
[speed_download] => 6818705
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => 13564110
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0.834829
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[redirect_url] => 
)
Error Code: 0
```

And these are the results of the same code working on 5.5

```
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 126.332476
[namelookup_time] => 0.000369
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => 
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 0
[local_ip] => 
[local_port] => 0
)
7 Failed to connect to www.someaddress.com/export/: Connection timed out
```

Of course I've researched and tried a lot of options before posting here, increasing the timeout time, trying an SSL version of the resource, and playing a lot with different curl_setopt yet, I always get failed to connect from the 5.5 app.

I'm aware that some changes have been made regarding the cURL extension on 5.5 but I can find by Google searches point to uploading problems, I've also tried fully different options like using file_get_contents and still nothing, just times out.

Both servers are located in the same place, and the URL is fully open so I really doubt the issue is within the file locations since still works perfectly when I run the code on the 5.3 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the URL I was trying to reach had my server's IP blocked!

I was able to contact the webmaster and white list my IP address, now the code works fine as it was without needing any changes.

Something else to keep in mind, what made this hard to debug it that it simply times out, with no error message or any of the sorts.

Answer (score 0):

From [php](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.changed-functions.php) manual

> Uploads using the @file syntax are now only supported if the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option is set to FALSE. CURLFile should be used instead.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
```

> There are "@" issue on multipart POST requests.

```
    Solution for PHP 5.5 or later:
    - Enable CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD.
    - Use CURLFile instead of "@".

    Solution for PHP 5.4 or earlier:
    - Build up multipart content body by youself.
    - Change "Content-Type" header by yourself.
```

[The CURLFile class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php#115161)

Comment: I'm aware of this, as I said in the comments, I'm aware of the CURLFile class, but this file object is only for uploading to a server from a local file you already have.

But, even if I take 

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fd);

out of the code and try just to grab the contents, I still get a time out on the resource...

Comment: also a reference link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180366/writing-the-following-curl-in-php

Comment: I did try using CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD and no luck, but I think I finally found the issue, apparently the server where I'm trying to get requests is denying everything from my servers IP, which would explain why the same code works on a different server, and also was able to download from any other website.

Thanks for your answer, still to confirm this as soon as the webmaster white list my IP's